# MySQL data to time value

Tags: mysql, mydbr

My table does an addition of how much time it takes to finish production.

It spits out values like: 192.5, or 100.25.

I'd like to know how to turn these values into something like this:

```
120 ---> 120 minutes

140.5 ---> 2 hours, 20 minutes, 30 seconds

30.25 ---> 30 mintes, 15 seconds
```

The formatting is unimportant, just would like to display time.

Comment: if you start dividing that number by 60 you will get first the hours, then with the modulo you will get the minutes and then again the seconds. But I'd go to do it with front end and not the db

Comment: @LelioFaieta I would totally agree however I am using this for reporting, therefore MyDBR outputs the values in report style, withdrawing the use of a frontend.

Comment: Well, wrap the logic up in a view and return this to MyDBR if this can't be done within the reporting tool.

Comment: ``DATE_FORMAT('2020-01-01' + INTERVAL `field` * 60 SECOND, '%H:%i:%s')``

Answer (score 1):

Crudely (I suspect that this can be written more elegantly)...

```
SET @x = 30.25;

SELECT FLOOR(@x/60) hours
     , FLOOR((@x/ 60-FLOOR(@x/60)) * 60) minutes
     , ROUND(((((@x/60)-FLOOR(@x/60))*60)-FLOOR((@x/60-FLOOR(@x/60))*60))*60,0) seconds;
+-------+---------+---------+
| hours | minutes | seconds |
+-------+---------+---------+
|     0 |      30 |      15 |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Use `DIV` operator instead of (`/`+`FLOOR`).

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE_FORMAT('2020-01-01' + INTERVAL `field` * 60 SECOND, '%H:%i:%s')
```

or

```
DATE_FORMAT('2020-01-01' + INTERVAL `field` * 60 SECOND, '%H hours %i minutes %s second')
```

or even

```
TRIM(LEADING '00 hours ' FROM DATE_FORMAT('2020-01-01' + INTERVAL `field` * 60 SECOND, '%H hours %i minutes %s second'))
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably more elegant.